# Multidimensional Matrix Newton's Method problem

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

I included 3 pictures (both as google drive or image below):

1. Implementing Newton's method.

- [2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1moc6wr6z-pijqpX3lHKcrwEPj-QbDeUS/view?usp=share_link)

2. Derivative\Jacobian of F.

- [3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ypTyT9mn39nqe0LAW_MGzON9C7f5glJ/view?usp=share_link)

3. The Assignment.

- [4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mwe584lVlSkcO9iAG4QCq5pGfiDlrgLU/view?usp=share_link)

My question for (1) \ (2) is:
Why are we able to have a 2x2 matrix for Jacobian?
How does the derivative of $$\frac{1}{|| x - a||}$$ yield: $$(x-a)^T$$ (see (2) ) in particular on the right side to give an outer product?

- I understand why these are necessary dimensionally, just not sure where they come from. We were given the F and F' so I really want to understand the derivation.

For (1) does my algorithm correctly implement one iteration?
I set my own constants.

- I'm used to Newton for single and for multidimensional and multiple equations. But in this case, it appears there is only one F equation, with multiple dimensions. yet somehow we 'create' a second equation when doing the Jacobian.
- Also in practice, I don't plan on using the inverse Jacobian I would bring it to the other side, but for this pseudo-code, it shouldn't matter.

Main question:
What are the 2 F equations? They seem to yield the 2x2 Jacobian.
Derivatives with column vectors?[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. I did:
-- 'I included 3 pictures (both as google drive or image below):'
those 3 links are the merged image below.

2. I wasn't able to upload 3 images.

Comment: First, please split these images up in a way that people can actually read them. (Or better yet, convert some of it to Mathjax.) To simplify notation, I'll take $a=0$ for the moment and write $r=\|x\|$. Then what I see in the linked notes is not quite as you describe: namely, they're claiming that the Jacobi matrices for $\ell(x/r)-x$ is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\ell}{r}-1\right)I-\ell\frac{xx^\top}{r^3}.$ This is tedious but straightforward to verify

Comment: First thanks;
1. So I can't split render them, as I stated, but maybe I can find a better merge software. But I can study and edit mathjax my 2 docs and just have an img of the question.

2. Thanks for the a = 0, suggestion, that does simplify some of the thinking.
2b. But  will still be a 2x2.
2c. And that tedious portion is exactly what my teacher said (then skipped ahead). 
so I think those two are still my questions. 
Do you know any resources or key terms I can search for to learn that?

Comment: Please don't share private storage links (like google drive) because many IT departments block them. Embed the images in the post with the button, or use imgur.com to link directly to an image and not an album.